Defining Properties of a Line
I'm trying to create an activity for my students where I give them graphical properties of a line and ask them to find its equation. Of course the easiest is something like: "Slope = 4, y-intercept = 5". But I want to move up in difficulty. Below is a list of graphical line properties that, given any pair, yields a unique line.

slope
y-intercept
x-intercept
point
a second point (only works if you have a "first" point as the other property)
distance to the origin
angle formed by the x-axis (or y-axis) and the line (or its normal). [There are 4 possible angles to reference, but they are all so closely related that I consider this one property.] (Cannot pair with slope, so maybe this is the same thing.)

So, for instance, I could ask for the equation of a line at 30$^\circ$ to the x-axis through the point (-2,9).
My question is: Did I miss anything? Are there any other graphical properties that, when paired with one of the above, gives a unique line?
Note 1: By "graphical properties" I mean something that can be read from the graph. So, for example, saying you know the x-coefficient in standard form does not qualify. Also, saying "Derivative" instead of "Slope" is not an additional property, just a re-phrasing of an existing one.
Note 2: The list above comes from considering defining parameters in various forms of a line, e.g. slope-intercept, point-slope, point-point, intercept-intercept, and normal form.
Note 3: I am purposely leaving "students" vague as I'm interested in properties at all levels, not some specific class. But generally I'm thinking of high school / college students in a math circle.

Would you accept calculus-related things like "signed area between the line and the x-axis between x=a and x=b"?

Sure. It's a little weird in that it alone gives the line uniquely. Other pieces of info requires a pair, but certainly this would make for a good question.

Oh, actually I take that back. You do need another property to make the line unique. Yes, this is good!

What about something like the least square regression line through three non-collinear points?

But generally I'm thinking of high school / college students in a math circle. --- It seems to me that after dealing with some of the ideas you've given here, the question you posed here is something you could present to the math circle participants.

Are you accepting or denying that a (straight) line is defined by two points, and all the rest is detail dependant on your frame of reference?
